# Creating an "Other;_____" field in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am creating a field (or column) in a table in my Access database using the "Lookup Wizard". My intent to use the lookup wizard is to type in the choices a user can select from, which I have been able to do successfully.

My question, is if there is a way to add an "Other" choice in my table selection where if chosen the user can manually enter some text. I'd like to be able to do this in the look-up wizard, so I do not have to create a new field for "Other" in my table. Basically I want my listbox to have the following format;

Choice 1

Choice 2

Choice 3

Other; _____________

Is there a way that this can be done in MS Access 2013?

Comment: I can help you but you'd have to be willing to use VBA, although, very minimally.

Comment: I'm willing to do that, this format is a necessity

Comment: The catch is that you'd have to get rid of "Other," my method works like this:-

The user can choose one of the existing selections. If he/she types something different, a message pops up saying what he/she entered wasn't on the list and asks if they'd still be interested in adding whatever they typed. If they select "yes," the code proceeds to adding the new selection even if it wasn't on the original list. Let me know if you want the code for that.

Comment: lookup fields in tables are evil...  This should be done at the form level, not the table level.